# I am getting different results odds ratio packages R and I don't know which one is correct

Tags: epidemiology

I am having an issue with calculating the odds ratio for my variables, when I used epitab from epitools I get a different result than using oddsratio()

I have tried changing the level of reference. This is the data:

Disease Feeding 1 0 zero-pasture 46 192 zero-graze 317 1212 pasture 38 266

Comment: There are different ways to estimate the true odds ratio, check `?fisher.test`.

Comment: Oh, I see, I will check the documentation for both packages and see if that could be the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful if you include a whole reproducible example with your question so that people can see which packages and functions you are using, and how you are using the functions.

It appears the difference is just in the different ways to calculate odds ratio available in the different functions.

If you use the `"wald"` method with the `oddsratio()` function, the results will agree with a simple calculation of dividing the ratio of the frequencies in the table. So, the following methods all yield the same results.

```
Input =("
Feeding         Disease1 Disease0
  zero-pasture  46        192
  zero-graze   317       1212
  pasture       38        266
")

Matrix = as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(Input), header=TRUE, row.names=1))

library(epitools)

oddsratio(Matrix, method="wald")$measure

   ###                        NA
   ### odds ratio with 95%  C.I.  estimate       lower    upper
   ###        zero-pasture        1.0000000         NA       NA
   ###        zero-graze          0.9160095  0.6489433  1.292984
   ###        pasture             1.6770833  1.0502500  2.678037


(1212/317) / (192/46)

   ### 0.9160095

(266/38) / (192/46)

   ### 1.677083


epitab(Matrix)$tab

   ###               oddsratio      lower     upper
   ### zero-pasture  1.0000000         NA        NA
   ### zero-graze    0.9160095  0.6489433  1.292984
   ### pasture       1.6770833  1.0502500  2.678037
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't pick up on that :)